# XML string array deserialize issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-web-api

I am using Visual Studio 2013. I have created a ASP.Net Web API project and I have added a controller, model and other related classes. Please find below my class details

**Products class**

```
public partial class Products{

   [XmlArray("Product")]      // Tried this also XmlArray(ElementName = "Product")
   [XmlArrayItem("productName")]
   public List<string> productName { get; set; }
}
```

In other class, I am initializing the Products class object as mentioned below

```
public Products Get()
{
    Products objProducts = new Products
    {
       productName = new List<string>
       {
                    "P1",
                    "P2",
                    "P3"
        };     
    };
    return objProducts;
}
```

Whenever I execute the url `(http://localhost/service/api/Products)` on browser I got below XML

```
<Products>
    <Product>
        <string>P1</string>
        <string>P2</string>
        <string>P3</string>
    </Product>
</Products>
```

I should like it if I could get this:

```
<Products>
    <Product>
        <productName>P1</productName>
        <productName>P2</productName>                       
        <productName>P3</productName>
    </Product>
<Products>
```

Comment: Can you please reformat your question to make it readable? (without the inline HTML and format the XML as code)

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with two nested tags - there is nothing in POC resembling that hierarchy. You can get away if you reorganize your POC classes.

There are two ways how web api serialize output into xml. See https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization for reference.

One is using `DataContractSerializer` (default) another is using `XmlSerializer`

```
// configure web api to use XmlSerializer
var xml = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter;
xml.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```

Now if you're using `XmlSerializer`:

```
public class Products
{
    [XmlElement("Product")]
    public ProductNameList Product { get; set; }
}

public class ProductNameList
{
    [XmlElement("productName")]
    public List<string> ProductName { get; set; }
}
```

Usage:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Products));
var stream = new MemoryStream();
serializer.Serialize(stream, new Products
{
  Product = new ProductNameList { ProductName = new List<string> { "aa", "bb" } }
});
var result = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(stream.ToArray());
```

Dumps:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Products xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Product>
    <productName>aa</productName>
    <productName>bb</productName>
  </Product>
</Products>
```

If you're using `DataContractSerializer`:

```
public class Products
{
    public ProductNameList Product { get; set; }
}

[CollectionDataContract(ItemName = "productName")]
public class ProductNameList : List<string>
{
}
```

Please note all `[Xml...]` attributes are ignored when you're using `DataContractSerializer` - your example is using them so I was under assumption that you use `XmlSerializer`.

Comment: I have updated the code of Products and ProductNameList class. I am intializing the Products class object as mentioned below
Products objVersionsResponse = new Products
{
   Product = new ProductList
   {
         productName = new List<string> { "v1",   "v2" }
   }
};
   
<Products>
 <Product>
  <productName>
   <string>v1</string>
   <string>v2</string>
  </productName>
 </Product>
</Products>

Instead of 
<Products>
 <Product>
  <productName>v1</productName>
  <productName>v2</productName>
 </Product>
</Products>

Comment: As I mentioned in my question I have created WebAPI project. When I executing it on a browser like http://localhost/service/api/Products, it shows be XML like above.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `[XmlElement("productName")]`

```
public partial class Products{

   [XmlArray("Product")] 
   [XmlElement("productName")]
   public List<string> productName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: XmlElement, XmlText, and XmlAnyElement cannot be used in conjunction with XmlAttribute, XmlAnyAttribute, XmlArray, or XmlArrayItem.